# Disabling cache in Excel / PowerBI for OData

Tags: c#, excel, odata, powerbi

In my project, I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.OData to create OData WebApi service.

I've noticed that all data returned from my OData WebApi service are cached inside Excel and/or PowerBI. I would like to avoid this situation. Ideally, I'd like to turn off caching for any data from my service.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Any attribute, response header?
In the past I have tried cache-control header but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable cache. But the following works fine.
After loading the data in powerbi or powerquery you need to follow the following steps

1: Go to File

2: Go to option and settings

3: Go to query options

4: Clear cache

This is the only way to do this, you and also reduce the cache to 5Mb. This might help upto some extent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm aware of this solution, but this still causes some user issues from time to time - like showing old, outdated data.

Comment: There is no way around at this time. Odata is still in developing stage so odata clients like excel nad powerbi is still in developing stage.

Comment: There is no way around at this time. Odata is still in developing stage so odata clients like excel and powerbi is still in developing stage.                          And as odata is normally used for large data set like for medical research, railways, flights etc where the client needs to draw graphs, so thatswhy I think that it should cache the data, and excel and powerbi have some minimum amount of cache. You can see that if you reduce the cache to 0Mb then it throws the error that there should be some minimum chache. So you need to clear the cache everytime you are loading the data.